# Did the complexity metric change?

Tags: sonarqube, complexity-theory

Are there any changes in metric complexity the way it measures in different versions of SonarQube for PL/SQL code?

The number of complexities on version 5.6.6 is much lower than that in version 4.5.4, even though I did not change the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to the version of SonarQube, but instead to the version of SonarPLSQL. Version 2.9 includes corrections to the calculation of Cyclomatic Complexity. Previously it was a mix between Cyclomatic Complexity and Essential Complexity (so extra points were added for early returns) but now it is purely Cyclomatic Complexity, so a drop in values is expected.

[SonarPLSQL 2.9 release notes](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10001&version=10569)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response Ann, I would check out the above and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Ann, May I know why do I only see complexity/file and not Complexity / Function in metrics for PL/SQL code, is this a known occurence.

Comment: That's a slippery concept in a language where not everything needs to be encapsulated in a function.